# Locking of file by specific set of processes

Tags: windows, file, locking

I am facing a scenario where I have to allow access to a file for multiple instances of the same executable, but deny access to the file to all other executables.

For example, if I have a file `foo.txt` and an executable `proc.exe` then any number of `prox.exe` instances should be able to access and modify `foo.txt` but no other process should be able to access or modify this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this based directly on which executable a process is running.  However, you can make your processes co-operate with one another, so that the only processes that can access the file are those that know how to do it.

One particularly simple approach would be to create a named file mapping object for the file using [CreateFileMapping()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Only processes that know the name of the file mapping would be able to access it.  However, you would then only be able to access the file via memory mapping, not via normal I/O functions.

[DuplicateHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provides another option, but because the duplicated handle shares a single file object you need to be very careful how you use it.  Overlapped I/O is probably the safest approach, as it explicitly supports multiple simultaneous operations on the same object.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. The CreateFileMapping and MapOfFile functions are good to go for windows. Can you also suggest something similar for Linux?

Comment: @sandeep: no, I'm not familiar enough with Linux to have any idea.  I recommend you post another question, similar to this one but tagged for Linux.